# Are ReLU a very bad choice as last layer for regression?

Tags: calculus, gradient-descent, neural-networks, backpropagation

Let's say that we have a very simple single layer neural network, and we can descrive the structure as following:
$$
a = Wx+b\\
o = ReLU(a)\\
J = (t - o)^2 \\\text{     online learning}
$$

however, when backpropagating the gradient to $W$ we have the following:
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial o}\frac{\partial o}{\partial a} \frac{\partial a}{\partial W}
$$
However, the second term is the derivative of the ReLU layer respect to the activation, which is a matrix (in this case a vector 1xN) that have element in $\{0,1\}$, which means that if we have a single neuron as output (in our case $o$), which (for example for bad choice of weights initialization) has always preactivation less than 0, the network will never learn anything, because the gradient will always be 0 (since $\frac{\partial o}{\partial a} = 0$)

I'm asking for regression, because maybe our target is always $>0$, and somebody might pick ReLU seeing that the domain matches

Comment: For MSE loss, it makes sense to make the last layer linear to scale to output variable. And indeed it doesn't make a lot of sense to add ReLU as the last layer in most cases. There is also problem with "dying" neurons even in internal layers, and there are different approaches to it - like using leaky relu or ELU as activation.

Comment: @mihaild thanks for the reply, I'm pretty familiar with NN, I'm just making an example to check if my hypothesis is correct (which is, if relu gets zero, then the gradient is not propagated through that neuron)

Comment: Each layer should be assessed not only by its activation function, but also by the interaction that function has with the cost function.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes, that's correct - if you use ReLU activation, and neuron for some reason gets only negative values on input, then it's input weights will never be updated.

Comment: @J.G. sure, but it's enough to have one between the activation value and the derivative of the activation function to be 0 in order to say that no gradient will be propagated through that neuron

Comment: @mihaild thank you, for some reason this wasn't making sense in my head